# Programatic way of finding out if your Slack app is approved/blocked by a workspace?

Tags: slack-api

I've got an increasing number of users that login to my web app with "Sign in with Slack" successfully, but then fail to add any further permissions at the following step (you can't have regular + `identity.*` scopes requested at the same time in the OAuth flow).

The reason is either the user isn't happy with the permissions being requested and closes the window, or the app is blocked by the workspace as it needs approval. If my app is blocked, there appears to be absolutely no feedback. Unfortunately, I have no idea which of these a customer experiences.

Is there a way to find out if my app requires approval for a workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slack doesn't currently provide any feedback to an app developer or owner as to why their app was not installed or approved. Often, organizations have security policies or other reasons for denying an app approval that would not be appropriate to share externally.

I'll take your feedback to the app directory team and see if there are ways we might be able to help solve this problem.